# ¿Como comparar el dato actual de una fila con el de la fila siguiente de un dataTable?C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatable

Tengo el siguiente datatable en un metodo de mi controller que recorre sus datos que son obtenidos de una query

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

//Obtengo query y los meto en el datatable y etc
sda.Fill(dt);

foreach (DataRow datos_tabla in dt.Rows) {
  System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(datos_tabla[0].ToString());
  System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(datos_tabla[1].ToString());
  System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(datos_tabla[2].ToString());
 }
```

El asunto está es saber como comparar si el dato actual, por ejemplo:
datos_tabla[0].ToString(); es distinto con el siguiente de la fila siguiente.

Por ejemplo, en datos_tabla[0].ToString(); se van mostrando todos los nombre. Quiero saber si el nombre actual que se va mostrando al recorrer el datatable es igual al nombre de la siguiente fila. Algo como asi:

```
  foreach (DataRow datos_tabla in dt.Rows) {

   If(datos_tabla[0].ToString())==datos_tabla[0].FilaSiguiente.ToString()){ 
     //acciones}

   }
 }
```

Necesito saber si un dato que se encuentra en la fila 0, como el nombre, es igual o no al nombre de la fila 1

Comment: cual es el objetivo que realizar lo que planteas ? con que finalidad. Lo pregunto porque quizas hay una forma mas simple de lograr lo que buscas si aplicaras linq

Comment: dependiendo si son iguales, llamo a una funcion que obtiene un valor y asi pasarlo a una lista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes cambiar de `Foreach` por un `for` y comparar con `Equals` que es la forma más adecuada de comparar `cadenas`, se accede a la siguiente fila aumentando tu variable iteradora de la siguiente manera

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count-1 ; i++)
  {
    if (dt.Rows[i][1].ToString().Equals(dt.Rows[i+1][1].ToString()))
         //aumenta el i para obtener la siguiente fila
    {
     Console.WriteLine("IGUALES");
    }

 }
```

> Si no restas el -1 tendrías una `exception` que te la detallo en la siguiente imagen

[image: Explicación Gráfica]

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de `foreach` puedes usar `for`:

```c#
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++ )
{
    if (dt.Rows[i]["nombre"].ToString() == dt.Rows[i + 1]["nombre"].ToString())
    {
        // acciones.
    }
}
```

En lugar de ***"nombre"***, también puedes usar el índice numérico de la columna o `columnIndex`. Por ejemplo, si la columna *"nombre"* tiene el índice **1**, entonces:

```c#
    if (dt.Rows[i][1].ToString() == dt.Rows[i + 1][1].ToString())
```